# ABB: No se imprimen valores al recorrerlo

Tags: c, algoritmos, árboles-binarios, árboles

Tengo esta implementación de un **árbol binario de búsqueda** en C; debo hacer 3 recorridos en él: preorden, enorden y postorden. El problema es que no me imprime nada y el código no tiene errores, supongo que lo que está mal es mi lógica, pero no encuentro el fallo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct t_tree{
    int value;
    t_tree* leftChild;
    t_tree* rightChild;
} BinarySearchTree;

void insert(BinarySearchTree* root, int x){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = (BinarySearchTree*) malloc(sizeof(BinarySearchTree));
        root->value = x;
        root->leftChild = NULL;
        root->rightChild = NULL;
    } else {
        if(root->value == x){
            printf("\n\tEse valor ya existe en el arbol");
            return;
        }
        if(x < root->value)
            insert(root->leftChild, x);
        else
            insert(root->rightChild, x);
    }
}

BinarySearchTree* search(BinarySearchTree* root, int x){
    if(root == NULL){
        printf("\n\tEl elemento no existe");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        if(root->value == x){
            printf("\n\tEl valor si existe");
            return root;
        }
        if(x < root->value)
            search(root->leftChild, x);
        else
            search(root->rightChild, x);
    }
}

void update(BinarySearchTree* root, int x, int newValue){
    BinarySearchTree* theChosenOne = search(root, x);
    if(theChosenOne != NULL)
        theChosenOne->value = newValue;
}

void remove(BinarySearchTree* root, int x){
    BinarySearchTree* theChosenOne = search(root, x);
    if(theChosenOne != NULL){
        if(theChosenOne->leftChild==NULL && theChosenOne->rightChild==NULL)
            free(theChosenOne);
        else {
            BinarySearchTree* explorer;
            if(theChosenOne->leftChild){
                explorer = theChosenOne->leftChild;
                while(explorer->rightChild)
                    explorer = explorer->rightChild;
                theChosenOne->value = explorer->value;
                free(explorer);
            } else if(theChosenOne->rightChild){
                explorer = theChosenOne->rightChild;
                while(explorer->leftChild)
                    explorer = explorer->leftChild;
                theChosenOne->value = explorer->value;
                free(explorer);
            }
        }
    }
}

void preOrder(BinarySearchTree* root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d ", root->value);
    preOrder(root->leftChild);
    preOrder(root->rightChild);
}

void inOrder(BinarySearchTree* root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    inOrder(root->leftChild);
    printf("%d ", root->value);
    inOrder(root->rightChild);
}

void postOrder(BinarySearchTree* root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    postOrder(root->leftChild);
    postOrder(root->rightChild);
    printf("%d ", root->value);
}

int main(){
    BinarySearchTree* ROOT = NULL;
    insert(ROOT, 5);
    insert(ROOT, 1);
    insert(ROOT, 9);
    insert(ROOT, 1);
    insert(ROOT, 8);
    insert(ROOT, 50);
    printf("\nRecorrido en pre-orden: ");
    preOrder(ROOT);
    printf("\nRecorrido en in-orden: ");
    inOrder(ROOT);
    printf("\nRecorrido en post-orden: ");
    postOrder(ROOT);
    free(ROOT);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La función `insert` tiene algunos errores que impiden que el arbol se pueda rellenar.

Lo primero que llama la atención de la función es que la misma recibe un puntero simple al nodo raiz y que no devuelve nada.

¿Por qué es esto significativo?

Porque al llamar a `insert`, la función recibe **una copia** del puntero a `root`. El usar una copia hace que ciertos cambios sean locales a la propia función. Se ve más facil sin punteros:

```
void func(int var)
{
  var = 10;
  printf("var=%d\n",var);
}

int main()
{
  var = 0;
  printf("var=%d\n",var);
  func(var);
  printf("var=%d\n",var);
}
```

Como no podía ser de otra forma, el resultado del programa es el siguiente:

```
var=0
var=10
var=0
```

Es decir, el cambio que se ha realizado dentro de la función es un cambio local... y con los punteros pasa exactamente lo mismo:

```
void func(int *var)
{
  *var = 10;
  var = (int*)1234;
}

int main()
{
  int* var = (int*)calloc(1,sizeof(int));
  printf("var=%d, &var=%x\n",*var,var);
  func(var);
  printf("var=%d, &var=%x\n",*var,var);
}
```

Si ejecutas el programa anterior, verás que mientras el `10` si es un cambio persistente, el valor `1234` se ha perdido. Esto sucede porque estás modificando la copia del puntero en vez de la región de memoria compartida por ambos punteros.

Pues bien, eso mismo está sucediendo en tu función:

```
void insert(BinarySearchTree* root, int x){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = (BinarySearchTree*) malloc(sizeof(BinarySearchTree)); // <<--- AQUI!!!
        root->value = x;
        root->leftChild = NULL;
        root->rightChild = NULL;
    } else {
      // ...
    }
}
```

La consecuencia es que la función es incapaz de añadir elementos al árbol... o al menos no puede hacerlo de forma que el cambio sobreviva a al función.

¿Soluciones?

Quizás lo más sencillo de implementar, dado tu código, sea modificar la función para que admita punteros dobles. Así la función podrá modificar los punteros alegremente:

```
void insert(BinarySearchTree** root, int x){
    if(*root == NULL){
        *root = (BinarySearchTree*) malloc(sizeof(BinarySearchTree));
        *root->value = x;
        *root->leftChild = NULL;
        *root->rightChild = NULL;
    } else {
        if(*root->value == x){
            printf("\n\tEse valor ya existe en el arbol");
            return;
        }
        if(x < *root->value)
            insert(&root->leftChild, x);
        else
            insert(&root->rightChild, x);
    }
}
```

Y, dado que hemos modificado la entrada de la función, hay que acordarse de modificar también las llamadas a la misma:

```
insert(&ROOT, 5);
```